# PHP intval of multibyte strings

Tags: php, utf-8

How does intval() change when using UTF-8 multibyte strings as opposed to regular one byte per character strings? Is it the same?

Comment: What do you expect intval() to give you from a multibyte string? e.g. from `123αβγ`. And why do you think that would be any different to `123abc`?

Comment: @MarkBaker it should give 123 for both, I think.

Comment: [So why don't you try it and see](https://3v4l.org/eVK0t)

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I did. I however wanted to make sure it is ok, I'm just now transitioning to utf-8 and I'm a beginner and don't want to take conclusions out of some echo tests I ran. I didn't encounter any issues, but I didn't encounter issues with trim() either and it seems like there are some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't distinguish string encodings internally. A string is simply an array of bytes. If you pass an UTF-8 string to `intval`, the function only sees the bytes of the encoded UTF-8 string. Given the nature of the UTF-8 encoding, `intval` will treat any non-ASCII character as a non-digit. So it doesn't make a difference whether you pass an ASCII, Latin1, or UTF-8 string.

Comment: Thank you, this is consistent with the testing I had done but I didn't want to bet anything on it based on a couple echo tests.